# Can anyone Id this flower?

Tags: species-identification, flowers

Small pink flower, started out as tiny buds, leaves look almost like Maple leaves..

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Try to tell us as much as you can about this flower. In which country did you find it? Which environment? What season? Do you know if it is a wild species or an ornemental species?

Comment: Location information is extremely important to species id questions @LindaMarie

Answer (score 5):

It's a mallow.

[image]

The leaves - they look like maple leaves - and the flower are identical.

Mallows are from the family Malvaceae, which includes food plants (okra, cocoa beans, kola nut), economic plants (cotton), and ornamentals (e.g. hibiscus) One species of this family (Althaea officinalis) is actually the original ingredient to make marshmallows.

I'm not sure which [mallow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malvaceae) it is (there are 243 genera with 4225+ species), but it's a common <s>weed</s> wildflower all over the world.

Comment: Nice answer - I agree on the classification, it's a shame theres so many species

Comment: @rg255 - Thanks. Yep. I've seen this one on my own property, and couldn't narrow it down further. There are so many. I've seen marsh mallow, rose mallow, and a bunch of others, but this one I could not identify.